# ajax onchange form submission is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i am trying to submit a form  using onchange event. my form contain check box, on check form should be submit and send the data to php and return value from php page.

bellow is my form

```
<form id="search_form" method="post">
<input class="le-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="filter1[]" value="<?=$bkey?>" /> <label><?=$bkey?></label>
<input class="le-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="filter2[]" value="<?=$bkey?>" /> <label><?=$bkey?></label>
<input class="le-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="filter3[]" value="<?=$bkey?>" /> <label><?=$bkey?></label>
<input class="le-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="filter4[]" value="<?=$bkey?>" /> <label><?=$bkey?></label>
</form>
```

and i am using ajax to send data and retrieve from php page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("change",'[type="checkbox"]',function(){
   var url = "protest.php";
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: $("#search_form").serialize(),
     success: function(data)
     {                  
        //$('.ajax_result').html(data);
        alert(data);
     }               
   });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

if the form is submitted php result is shown in `alert(data)` bellow is my php example page

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST)){
echo "data submited";
}
?>
```

first of all its not working and in alert message is showing source code please check the image[image]

i am unable find the issue

Comment: getting any error in the console??

Comment: not showing any error when i print using id like $('.ajax_result').html(data); , its showing the same page inside the page

Comment: Try this `var url = "/protest.php";` (add slash to url)

Comment: use ... `dataType: "html" `

Comment: use die() after your echo

Comment: ho is that so simple i just added / and datatype: "html". its working grate. i don't know which one is worked but its working. it think / is missing

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Use `exit` after your `echo`. This will also work.

Comment: you should retrive the data in json format.

dataType : "json"

Comment: There was problem with Ajax url. If do not add slash to url – request sends to url like this http://www.ournestonline.com/products/3/classic-traditional-wear/protest.php. But right url is http://www.ournestonline.com/protest.php

Comment: if i use json is dataType how to retrieve data back? do i need to use any json encode

Answer (score 0):

Just put `exit` after your `echo`.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST)){
echo "data submited";
exit;
}
?>
```